# Find $x$ where $f(e^{(x+1)})=x-\ln(x)$ approaches one.

Tags: limits, functional-equations

Given that
$$
x \in [1,\infty) \quad f(e^{(x+1)})=x-\ln(x)
$$

and

$$
\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=1
$$

Find $a$.

---

I got to the point:
$$
\ln(a)-\ln(\ln(a)-1)=2
$$

But from there on I could not get to $a=e^2$ which is the answer. (*I can see* that $a=e^2$ is the answer, I just cannot show it.)

Comment: If $x=1$ you get $f(e^2)=1$, so if $f(x)$ is continuous at $e^2$ then certainly $\lim_{x \to e^2} f(x)=1$.

Comment: If $a>e^2$, then $a=e^{x+1}$ for some $x>1$, and $x=e^y$ for some $y>0$. Then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)=x-\ln x=e^y-y>1$. We conclude that certainly $a\le e^2$. The given conditions tell us nothing about $f(x)$ for $x<e^2$; if we assum ethe domain of $f$ is just $[e^2,\infty)$ then $$e=e²$ is the only possible (and obviously working) solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have that
$$\frac{a}{e^2}=\ln{\left(\frac{a}e\right)}$$
We can proceed to get
$$\exp{\left(\frac{a}{e^2}\right)}=\frac{a}e$$
$$1=\frac{a}e\exp{\left(-\frac{a}{e^2}\right)}$$
$$-\exp{(-1)}=-\frac{a}{e^2}\exp{\left(-\frac{a}{e^2}\right)}$$
Now with the equation in this form we can see that
$$-\frac{a}{e^2}=-1$$
$$a=e^2$$
In fact there are infinite complex solutions given by
$$a=-e^2W_k\left(-\frac1e\right)$$
where $W_k(z)$ is the $k$th branch of the Lambert-W function.

Comment: Thanks. Did not know the technique in line 4. ($-exp(-1)=...$. What is it called? This question was asked in a high school test. I am surprised that there is not a simpler approach.

Comment: I multiplied by $-\frac1e$ both sides but wrote $\frac1e=\exp{(-1)}$ to make it clear what I was later equating together.

Comment: just to make it clear: do we deduce $-exp(-1)=-\frac{a}{e^2}exp(-\frac{a}{e^2})$, because if $ae^a=be^b$ then $a=b$?

Comment: Yes that is what I intended for you to realise. Sometimes there are two real values that give the same value of $xe^x$, but in the case of $-e^{-1}$ there is only one - $-1$.

Answer (score 4):

Substituting $$t=e^{x+1}$$ we get $$x=\ln(t)-1$$ so we get
$$f(t)=\ln(t)-1-\ln(\ln(t)-1)$$

Comment: How do I get $a=e^2$ from this point on. This is where I get confused.

Comment: If the limit is equal to $$1$$ we get $$\ln(a)-\ln(\ln(a)-1)=2$$

Comment: and we get $$\ln\left(\frac{a}{\ln(a)-1}\right)=2$$

Comment: and we arrive at $$a=e^2(\ln(a)-1)$$

Comment: I also got to this point. How do I get $a=e^2$ from here on?

Comment: Ok, you will get the equation $$\frac{a}{e^2}=\ln\left(\frac{a}{e}\right)$$

Comment: We must SEE that $$a=e^2$$

Comment: I can see that $a=e^2$ is the answer, I just do not see how we show it.

Comment: Try a numerical method.